# Is there a name for an over-category where the morphisms to the object is required to be a monomorphism?

Tags: category-theory

Let there be a category $C$. I would like to work on the category $C/c$ where the morphism to $c$ is a monomorphism.

I go like this:
Let $C_m$ be the subcategory of $C$ where all morphisms are monomorphisms, and work in $C_m/c$.

My question is: is there a name for this construction in category theory?

Comment: I don't know of a specific name, but this is essentially the first step in constructing the subobject poset. So maybe the "subobject category" would be a good name (if you want to give it a name)?

Comment: @MarkKamsma: Oh, I see what you mean. I don't necessarily want to give it a name, but knowing of an existing name makes it easier to look for information about it. Looking for "subobject poset" leads me to interesting information already. Thank you.

Comment: Ah I see, I will just convert my comment into an answer then, considering it is more helpful than I initially thought.

Answer (score 4):

What you are describing is the first step in constructing the subobject poset of $c$. So let us recall how that goes.

> **Definition.** Given monomorphisms $f: x \to c$ and $g: y \to c$, we say write $f \leq g$ if there is an arrow $h: x \to y$ such that $gh = f$.

*Exercise:* prove that $h$ itself must be a monomorphism, and that it is unique.

> **Definition.** The above definition defines a pre-order on the monomorphisms into $c$. We say that two such monomorphisms $f: x \to c$ and $g: y \to c$ are *equivalent* if $f \leq g$ and $g \leq f$.

*Exercise:* if $f$ and $g$ are equivalent, then the arrows witnessing $f \leq g$ and $g \leq f$ are actually isomorphisms. So in particular, $x$ and $y$ are isomorphic.

> **Definition.** A *subobject* of $c$ is an equivalence class of monomorphisms (under the previously defined equivalence relation). We denote by $\operatorname{Sub}(c)$ the collection of all subobjects of $c$. The pre-order on monomorphisms then becomes a partial order on subobjects, making $\operatorname{Sub}(c)$ into a partial order.

*Exercise:* verify that we indeed get a partial order on $\operatorname{Sub}(c)$.

This is the basic construction of the subobject poset. In the original question you basically just do not take the equivalence classes.

---

A few interesting notes about these subobjects.

Subobjects often have very natural descriptions. For example, in the category of sets they are just subsets and $\operatorname{Sub}(c)$, for a set $c$, is essentially just the powerset of $c$.

I wrote "collection" on purpose for $\operatorname{Sub}(c)$, and not "set", because it can be too big to be a set. For example, if we consider the class of ordinals with the reverse order as a category, then $0$ (or in fact, any object in that category) has a proper class of subobjects. However, in most categories we consider $\operatorname{Sub}(c)$ is a set, we call such categories *well-powered*.

Different kind of categories can guarantee a lot of extra structure on $\operatorname{Sub}(c)$. For example, in the category of sets it is always a Boolean algebra. In a topos it is always a Heyting algebra. In the category of groups we get a complete lattice (subobjects are subgroups there).

Comment: In your first exercise, you should also demand to prove that such a monomorphism $h$ is unique if it it exists. It looks straightforward to prove given the definition of a monomorphism, and it may seem obvious to someone well versed into CT, but stating it would intuitively map better to the idea of deriving a preorder from it. Your $\leq$ seems to sprout out of nowhere, at least to me.

Comment: @Laurent I added that. Although to define a pre-order this $h$ wouldn't need to be unique. We can just say $f \leq g$ if such an $h$ exists, then proving that this defines a pre-order does not use uniqueness of $h$ (or even that it is mono, but you were interested in monos, hence the exercise)

Comment: Done the exercices. Interestingly enough, you only need $f$ to be a mono in order for $h$ to be a mono, and $g$ to be a mono in order for $h$ to be unique.